# How does proposal N4502 work? (the "detection idiom")

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I was looking at the proposal [N4502](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf), and have been trying to wrap my head around it.  I'm good up to section 5, but then what I thought I understood falls away.  Perhaps it is just how I'm looking at it.  Given the following:

> ```
> // primary template handles all types not supporting the operation:
> template< class, template<class> class, class = void_t< > >
> struct
>   detect : false_type { };
> // specialization recognizes/validates only types supporting the archetype:
> template< class T, template<class> class Op >
> struct
>   detect< T, Op, void_t<Op<T>> > : true_type { };
> ```
>
> To use this detect metafunction, we supply it with another
>   metafunction (i.e., a meta-callback) that fills the role of the
>   archetypal expression. For example, here is an implementation of the
>   `is_assignable` type trait:
>
> ```
> // archetypal expression for assignment operation:
> template< class T >
> using
>   assign_t = decltype( declval<T&>() = declval<T const &>() )
> // trait corresponding to that archetype:
> template< class T >
> using
>   is_assignable = detect<void, assign_t, T>;
> ```

I should be able to check if a type is assignable.  No example of how it is used is given, so I'm assuming that it should be as easy as:

```
static_assert(is_assignable<int>::value, "Not assignable.");
```

Now just looking at this, doesn't look right.  I don't see any way that `assign_t` is going to interact with the type `T`.

How this reads to me is:

```
is_assignable<int>
-> detect<void, assign_t, int>
```

Which will then fail to match any specialization and go to the base case which inherits from `std::false_type`.

Compiling this [here](http://rextester.com/IGZS87648) seems to agree with my understanding.

So, what am I missing?  How is this supposed to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo, it should be

```
template< class T >
using is_assignable = detect<T, assign_t>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98fbf7784c545845)

Comment: I've already fixed that typo on the demo.

Comment: I don't see any edits in this regard. You still have typo-ed `detect<void, assign_t, int>` (!= `detect<int, assign_t, void>`) both in your question and in your link.

Comment: > Compiling this [here](http://rextester.com/IGZS87648) seems to agree with my understanding.

Comment: As I said, you have an inversion between `T` and `void`: `is_assignable = detect<void, assign_t, T>;` should be `is_assignable = detect<T, assign_t, void>;`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that.